# How do I add fancy-type to blueprint using compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I am developing a rails 3 app with compass. I did 'compass init rails --using blueprint/basic' and 'compass init rails --using blueprint/buttons'.

Still, .alt class is not available. It's in blueprint/fancy-type. The doc says that I need to do "@import "blueprint/fancy-type". I did in stylesheets/screen.scss file. But it doesn't work yet.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

To install the fancy type plugin:

1. Import the fancy_type module: `@import "blueprint/fancy_type"`
2. Mix in fancy-type to your project's body or at the top level of your stylesheet: `body { @include fancy-type; }`

http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/blueprint/fancy_type/#mixin-fancy-type-scss